# Topology of Anti-de Sitter manifold with black hole

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, mathematical-physics, topology

I'm interested in understanding the topology of space-time with a black hole.  In other words how does having a black hole affect quantities such as the fundamental group, de-Rham cohomologies, Euler character etc of the background space-time manifold. Answering in light of anti-de Sitter space would be very helpful.

Comment: Site policy is one question per post...consider deleting your black hole question and making a new post for it alone.

Comment: Maybe read this?

http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9808032